# PHP SOAP запрос к вебсерверу

Tags: php, веб-сервер, soap

Доброе утро, пытаюсь отправить SOAP запрос на вебсервер 1с. Код запроса:

```
function getSoap($query){
/*
* Конфиги
*/
$username = "Логин";
$password = 'Пароль';
$soapUrl = "урл";
$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",  
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $soapUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response=str_replace('','',str_replace("\t",'',str_replace("\r",'',str_replace("\n",'',trim($response)))));
return $response;}
$xml_posts='<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ru="ru.umc">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ru:GetListClinic/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';


$clinics=getSoap($xml_posts);
print_r($clinics);
```

SOAP запрос правильный, выдал 1сник, у него запрос работает. Я же вместо ответа получаю просто список всех методов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уверен, ваш $soapUrl в конце выглядит как '****?wsdl', что и возвращается. Endpoint URL должен быть отличным от него.

Comment: Да, заканчивается на ws1.1cws?wsdl

Comment: Ну так посмотрите у вашего коллеги, у которого всё работает, на какой адрес он шлёт свои запросы. Да в списке, который у вас на экране - где-то в конце будет Endpoint.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php ?